# making my own HIFI portable audio dac for raspberry pi zero w

Tags: audio-playback, diy

i am currently thinking to setup a portable volumio audio player

something like this one
https://www.allo.com/sparky/miniboss-rpi-zero.html
(i know i can order this instead nut my location(India) is charging double the cost)

all i need in my dac is a low noise floor(-110db)
and minimal Harmonic distortion

so what dac chip should i buy and how to set that up

PS.i am totally new to raspberry pi and other stuff

Comment: Please note that shopping requests are explicitly off-topic due to our policies. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 0):

The pHAT DAC seems to be popular.  I have 2 of them, but I haven't done a lot with them yet to give any opinion. I got them because of their popularity and the fact that they are pi zero sized, and the specs seem reasonable. Getting it to work with any of the rpis is slobberproof. Pretty close to plug and play.